# ZeroMq recv not blocking

Tags: c#, c++, zeromq

I'm attempting to learn ZeroMq for  project at work although my background is in C#, and in the most simplest of tests I seem to have an issue where the `socket.recv(...)` call will block for the first received message, but after this throws an exception because the amount of data received is -1.

Currently my 'server' is:

```
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_REP);
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");

while (true)
{
    zmq::message_t message;
    if (socket.recv(&message))
    {
        auto str = std::string(static_cast<char*>(message.data()), message.size());
        printf("Receieved: %s\n", str.c_str());
    }
}
```

This is basically from following the first example server within the ZeroMq documentation.

I'm pushing **1** bit of data from a C# 'client' using this code:

```
using (var context = new ZContext())
using (var requester = new ZSocket(context, ZSocketType.REQ))
{
    requester.Connect(@"tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
    requester.Send(new ZFrame(@"hello"));

    requester.Disconnect(@"tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
}
```

Now I start the server, then start the client. I correctly receive the first message and I am correctly able to print this.
But now when I hit `socket.recv(&message)` again the code won't block but will instead throw an exception because the underlying `zmq_msg_recv(...)` returns a value of -1.

I'm unsure why this is occurring, I cannot see why it is expecting another message as I know that there is nothing else on this port. The only thing I came across is calling `zmq_msg_close(...)` but this should be called as part of the `message_t` destructor, which I have confirmed.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong in terms of the socket setup or how I'm using it for the `recv(...)` call to stop blocking?

Comment: What does the `'@'` character do? I don't have that in my code.

Comment: Ah I see, it makes the string literal. So it cannot use the escape character `'\'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you cannot receive 2 requests in a row with the REQ-REP pattern.

In the Request-Reply Pattern each request demands a reply. Your client needs to block until it receives a reply to its first request. Also, your server needs to reply to the requests before it services a new request.

Here is a quote referring to your exact issue from the [guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc10).

> The REQ-REP socket pair is in lockstep. The client issues zmq_send()
>   and then zmq_recv(), in a loop (or once if that's all it needs). Doing
>   any other sequence (e.g., sending two messages in a row) will result
>   in a return code of -1 from the send or recv call. Similarly, the
>   service issues zmq_recv() and then zmq_send() in that order, as often
>   as it needs to.

Comment: Well just goes to show that I should pay attention to the full part of the documentation. I've managed to resolve my issue by sending an empty message after I've finished processing the received message. Thanks.